# How to Show that $y + W$ is a subspace of $V$ iff $y\in W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble with a question from an introductory Linear Algebra book. It goes: "Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$, let $y\in V$, and define the set $y+W=\{x\in V|x=y+w, w\in W\}$. Show that $y + W$ is a subspace of $V$ iff $y\in W$."

The if part seems reasonably straightforward. if $y\in W$ then $y+W$ is non-empty since it at least contains y because $w=0\in W$. Also $(y+w)+(y+w_2)=2y+(w+w_2)\in y+W$ since $2y\in V$ and $w+w_2\in W$. Similarly $c(y+w)\in y+W$. Is this correct? and how would one prove the only if part?

Comment: If $y\in W$ then $-y\in W$, so you can easily show $y+W = W$. If $y\notin W$ then $0\notin y+W$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You proof isn't quite correct - the part about sums and scalar multiplication is not sufficient. For example: $2y + (w + w_2) \in y + W$ does *not* follow from the fact that $2y \in V$ and $w + w_2 \in W$. Rather, you need to represent the vector as the sum of $y$ and a vector in $W$, e.g.

$$y + \big(y + w + w_2\big)$$

Now this *is* in $y + W$ because $y + w + w_2 \in W$. A similar issue exists for the scalar multiplication part.

---

For the other direction: every subspace contains the zero vector. Under what conditions can $0 \in y + W$?

Comment: Would it be that if $y+W$ is a subspace of $V$ then we would need some $x=0$, which means $y=-w\in W$?

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}$

Comment: Thank you. This was a very helpful answer.